# get all records between two dates spring boot jpa

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have one table which includes attendance of students with date.
School will closed in case of weekends. So there will be no records for saturday and sunday.

Suppose i want get records for given month, then by using date between query i can get all records of particular students but it will includes only those records which attendance is marked.

In this case, sunday and monday dates are not there so these records will be skip.

My question is I want null values if date is not present for given month

Expected result :

```
[
{
    "date":"2021-01-08"
},
{
    "date":"2021-01-09"
},
null,
{
    "date":"2021-01-11"
},
null,
null,
null,
{
    "date":"2021-01-15"
}
```

]

I want above response if records not exists,
What will be the query for this scenario?

Comment: Sounds like an outer join.  Try creating the query within the database console/tool first, then translate to java.  [This](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-join-types#outer) might help.

Comment: not returning null values..using left join query